# Can I borrow others' Windows installation CD to install it on my laptop?

Tags: windows, installation

My laptop is T400 coming with 32-bit Windows 7 Home edition. Since T400 CPU is 64-bit, I am considering to install 64-bit Windows instead, probably Windows 7 or 8 Home or Professional or Ultimate. I don't have the installation CD or DVD of any of the OSes. If I can find someone has one, is it allowed to borrow  and install it on my laptop?

Comment: Do do not fully agree. The question is not just "Where can I get install media or ISOs", but also on legal aspects. (The "is it allowed to borrow" part). 

[Where do I download Windows 7 (legally from Microsoft)?](http://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-do-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft) does have the line *Yes it is legal as long as you have a legitimate key", but I feel that that one line is insufficient to answer this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I can find someone has one, is it allowed to borrow and install it on my laptop?

Using a different CD/DVD is not a problem. You can even download the ISOs from a safe source (See [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-do-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft)).

However you will need a legal CoA. In most cases the CoA you got when you bought the 32 bit version of windows 7 will work fine for the 64 bit version (and do so legally).

In the case of OEMs there sometimes are exceptions, so check that before installing.

Comment: What is CoA? My current Windows 7 is 32-bit and home version. Can I use the same CoA for 64-bit and Profesional version, Windows 7 or 8?

Comment: Certificate of Authority. The key you need to enter. (The thing which looks like this: ABCDE-12345-FGHIJ-67890-KLMN)

Comment: A key for windows 7 **home** will only work on windows 7 home (either 32 or 64 bit).

Comment: Is CoA different for different person, different computer, or can it be shared between different persons and computers?

Comment: YOu get the CoA when you buy a license for the OS. Usually you get one CoA and are allowed to install it on one computer. You are allowed to move it to another computer, but not use it on two computer simultaneouly. (E.g. install windows on a laptop, enter the key and use it. Then wipe the whole laptop and install windows on a desktop and activate it with the same key).

Comment: @Hennes but if the CoA is included with the PC (oem) and not bought separately it is not allowed to transfer it to a new pc.

Comment: Yes, that is true for OEM bought licenses. However the OPs main question was about installing a regular 64 bit windows on the same PC. So this this particular case that does not apply.

Comment: Thanks! Is CoA same as "product key"?

Comment: Yes. CoA is the same. One is what it is commonly called, I think the other is Microsoftspeak.